# Typescript Pick optionnal unset variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, casting

I'm trying to use the "pick" function of typescript to get all the possible values of my objects.
My objects have optional attributes so they are not necessarily set

```js
const foo = [
    {
      name: 'index',
    },
    {
      name: 'id',
      type: 'number',
    },
    {
      name: 'error',
    },
  ] as const

type ElementArg<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer ElementType>
  ? Pick<ElementType, 'name' | 'type'>
  : never

type result = ElementArg<typeof foo>
//result : {name: "index" | "id" | "error"}
//expected : {name: "index" | "id" | "error" type: "number" | "undefined"}
```

and I also try to convert "type" attribut to a type with :

```js
type typeDecoder<T> = T extends 'number' ? number
  : T extends 'number[]' ? number[]
    : T extends 'string' ? string
      : T extends 'string[]' ? string[]
        : T extends 'boolean' ? boolean
          : T extends 'undefined' ? undefined
            : never;
```

but I think there is a better way to do it and I don't know where to use my function

Comment: I don't get the same error as you when using that code, [even when using `as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaBYAUDXMDe2eeYAhgLYCmAXDAOQCWYAJpQB50A0ReAvtzjyFBxMlVqNmXHsSgBPAA416YAK7kARpQBO0kTH4yCR3GOV0d2kLoHFDggLoxSEGKEhRs2eUpgBRABtKKjAoAEFtAHMAHgAVGHYoShZXACVKUmZwALkI7VI5aNUwAGswEAB3MAA+apQYeMTk5jSMrLAcvILopjgdfyCQqFjFSmqeAH4YAAUGYBLowODk4dHOFQpKOhgAH3ofLfHBWjBKADcdLywDmG1KCFUA2FQloYiYg5A4eEQjgHo-ngAHoTIA)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the type I would like to have either.
In yours there is undefined specified but it's because of the first object which doesn't have the "type" attribute. But then I would like the result to be "number"|undefined in the case you show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something to work:

```
type ElementArg<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, R extends {} = {}> = T extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Rest]
  ? ElementArg<Rest, {
    [K in keyof First | keyof R]:
      K extends keyof R
        ? K extends keyof First
          ? R[K] | First[K]
          : R[K] | "undefined"
        : K extends keyof First
          ? First[K]
          : never
  }>
  : R;
```

The main idea is that we loop through each of the elements in the tuple and then we add to the result we accumulate.

```
T extends readonly [infer First, ...infer Rest]
```

Here we get the first element and the rest as a tuple. Next is this big chunk:

```
  ElementArg<Rest, {
    [K in keyof First | keyof R]:
      K extends keyof R
        ? K extends keyof First
          ? R[K] | First[K]
          : R[K] | "undefined"
        : K extends keyof First
          ? First[K]
          : never
  }>
```

We use `ElementArg` again on the remaining elements, and then the long complicated mapped type correctly adds this element's contents to the results.

The logic is like this:

- For each key in the element or result
- If the key is a key of the result

  - If the key is a key of the element

    - Add the key's value to the result
  - Otherwise

    - Add `"undefined"` to the result
- Or else if the key is a key of the element

  - This is a new key we add to the result

And finally if the first step where we attempt to get the first element does not work, that means `T` is empty and we are done, so we return `R`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaBYAUDXMDe2eeYAhgLYCmAXDAOQCWYAJpQB50A0ReAvtzjyFBxMlVqNmXHsSgBPAA416YAK7kARpQBO0kTH4yCR3GOV0d2kLoHFDggLoxSEGKEhRs2eUpgBRABtKKjAoAEFtAHMAHgAVGHYoShZXACVKUmZwALkI7VI5aNUwAGswEAB3MAA+ThhUhLYklIJeFFbq9vjE5OZXbQyssBz0JjgdGAAxBm1oOoA6RbGJ9OgHHgB+fyCQ8Kjo1ag64WI0AGkYJhgSyjkQOCmZ6BgAH2vb+-qHahMYC56Wjc7g9Ur9cFt-k1eq4gZ9prNPPpiOD6ucnG94dA0WC8LRUmjXjAAETFVhwJiUZhEnG0SHNPrvYGPBE4lGYqDYpHI2hgSgANx0PF41R4eIA3F4sD5KDABhBVAFYKhAsFknsYtLPggQCKsAB6PV4AB6GyAA)