# How to get types for values from objects in an array when the objects don't all have the same keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following array:

```
const a = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Z'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Y'
  },
] as const
```

I'm trying to derive a type that is the union type of the `title` keys if they exist, e.g. `'Z' | 'Y'`. I am at a loss as to how to accomplish this though.

I've tried extracting the types using bracket notation, but because the keys aren't on every object, the type is `any`.

```
// The type here is `any`
type Titles = typeof a[number]['title']
```

I've tried handling this with conditional types as well, but I'm really out of my depth there and can't get it to work.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588164/typescript-pick-optionnal-unset-variable/71588956#71588956) question is kinda related. Hopefully you can take my answer and make it work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @kellys! That got me mostly there. It's bewildering why something so seemingly simple should take so much type gymnastics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost correct, but property 'title' does not exist on every member of type `typeof a[number]`.

You can filter union members with [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type.

```ts
type AElem = typeof a[number];
type AElemWithTitle = Extract<AElemWithTitle, {title: string}>;
type ATitles = AElemWithTitle['title']
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=40&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gKBjA3hzMCWAJgFwwCMANLplPlADYCmpA5AFou4C+VmOeBEjABMvGD1z88RUgGYxNOk1YBNTpgkBdeBBihIUANxo0UAJ4AHRjACCAUSYBbJDHNWQAM3gowAV0cARowATprGbtb2TgDqdAAWACpK1sh2AB5QwXDAUAA8UYyOFNi0DMww0MH4YADmXAB84ZaRSWW6yAWOsVCJySgspUwsYSZAA)

Comment: Very nice! `Extract` is always one of those types I forget existed. @ray-gesualdo should accept this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lesiak! That was exactly what I was looking for!

For posterity, here's my final solution with a single type used to pull the values: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gKBjA3hzMCWAJgFwwCMANLplPlADYCmpA5AFou4C+VmOeBEjABMvGD1z88RUgGYxNOk1YBNTpgkBdeBBihIUANxo0UAJ4AHRjACiADygAnOMCgBpRmYBqcegFdGCAAeXAAVGEYHRjBCXQAlRjhCcHozAEFHZzMgvzAAazAQAHcwAD4xDzMIqJjdaEd8MABzNFKkWwdnVyDQlDA-AFsAI0ZHTQpsVDzPAjAYSs1SXILiua5SlAWTcysYUKVA9vsnF3dPH39AoJ3GEAAzeAmWWgZGFlK0IA)